# How to draw Highchart points on a JPG image

Tags: highcharts

I can draw Highcharts fine and would now like to overlay symbols on a JPG image.
Is it possible to draw on a JPG image using Highchart symbols? 
An example to get me started would be lovely...

Comment: Simple mockup how should this look like would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with [`plotBackgroundImage`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.plotBackgroundImage). Note that scale and perspective of the chart area to the image area would be important. This method is only really to be used to make the chart "pretty" not to impart meaning.